# How to share dependencies in package.json definition using yarn 2?

Tags: yarnpkg, package.json, yarnpkg-v2

We are using **yarn workspace 2** monorepo project.

Our problem is, that there a 10 miniproject contains (for example):

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^4.0.2"
  }
```

Is there any stategy how to define some ROOT parent of package.json and exnted it in childs?

Like:
Parent:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^4.0.2"
  }
```

Child:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    ...Parent, // will use "typescript": "^4.0.2"
  }
```